# Unable to reload only the selected cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to reload only the selected cell in particular when tapping a picture in a cell.But i got the error cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'in this line: loadPostsValue(indexPath: IndexPath)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
        print(indexPath)
        loadPostsValue(indexPath: IndexPath)
    }

    func loadPostsValue(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        posts.removeAll()
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("posts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if  let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                guard let titleText = dict["title"] as? String else{return}
                let locationDetails = dict["location"] as! String
                let captionText = dict["caption"] as! String
                let photoUrlString = dict["photoUrl"] as! String
                let priceText = dict["price"] as! String
                let categoryText = dict["category"] as! String
                let usernameLabel = dict["username"] as! String
                let profileImageURL = dict["pic"] as! String
                let heartInt = dict["heart"] as! Int
                let timestampString = dict["timestamp"] as! String
                let post = Post(titleText: titleText, captionText: captionText, locationDetails: locationDetails, photoUrlString: photoUrlString, priceText: priceText,categoryText: categoryText, usernameLabel: usernameLabel, profileImageURL: profileImageURL, heartInt: heartInt, timestampString: timestampString)
                self.posts.append(post)
                print(self.posts)
                self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want `indexPath` - small i,  not `IndexPath`

Comment: I think you are passing the IndexPath class object instead of passing the reference   indexPath.

Comment: But i tried passing IndexPath in my code. I was getting error "Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'". May be you should clean the xcode CMD+SHIFT+K and then re build the code to get the compilation error, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the required `indexPath` as below,

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
    print(indexPath)
    loadPostsValue(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Currently you are not passing an object of `IndexPath` instead you are passing its `Type` which `compiler` is complaining about. Also `indexPathsForSelectedItems` is an `array` of all selected item so you should retrieve the first `indexPath` if your `collectionView`'s multiple selection is off.

**Edit** I think a straightforward way is to not use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` when you already have the selected `indexPath` from the delegate method itself. You can simply pass that as below,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    loadPostsValue(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

As you mentioned in the comments, i think if you just want to update the likes count, you can do it as below,

```
func loadPostsValue(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("posts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            guard let titleText = dict["title"] as? String else{ return }
            let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]
            post.heartInt = dict["heart"] as! Int
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this : Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @LionelTan as you are manipulating the `dataSource`(`self.posts.append(post)`) of the `collectionView` so you might have to insert that item first before reload. You can verify your code by commenting out that line where you are appending a new post.

Comment: When a user tapped on the like button of a post, the number of likes will increase.As i would like only that specific post to be reloaded or better still would be just the number of likes of that post.In the database, the number of likes would change alr,but just that i am not sure how do i just reload that portion.The listener of firebase is asynchronous which means that i would delay for 0.1 seconds using a completion handler before i load the post.But i am not sure how to load just a post or better still just the number of likes, instead of all the posts.

Comment: In that case, you should just update the likes count in your model and reload that cell the same way you are doing. I believe you should not be doing `posts.removeAll()` and `self.posts.append(post)`.

Comment: In the `observe` callback you should get the old post object and update its properties with new data. I will put this in the answer. I think that might solve your issue.